# How do I center text in a Horizontal StackLayout?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I have this StackLayout that I used to create a Navigation Bar in XAML. This Horizontal StackLayout contains a button and label. The problem is that the text is not exactly centered and I cant seem to get it perfectly in the middle. Can someone please help me center this text in this StackLayout? I'm using Xamarin by the way.

```
<!-- Nav Bar-->
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="45" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Teal}">
  <StackLayout.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="10,0,0,0"
                Android="0,0,0,0"
                WinPhone="0,0,0,0" />
  </StackLayout.Padding>
  <Button x:Name="btnBack" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          Command="{Binding BackCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding CanGoBack}" />
  <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding TitleBarText}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
</StackLayout>
```

As you can see the App Title is not centered...

Comment: The 'Label' is centered in the _remaining_ space (after you subtract the button).  That's just how StackLayout works.  This might be easier to accomplish with a different type of layout.  I think that AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout would work better in this situation.  If you want, I'll post an answer using a to accomplish this.

Comment: Hey Thanks! I'm really stuck on this so that would be a really big help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The StackLayout isn't great when you want to put a View in a specific location.  It's good when you have a number of views, and you want them all to appear in a reasonable way.

When you want something pixel perfect, there are two great layouts:

- AbsoluteLayout
- RelativeLayout

To your specific issue, I would say to use an AbsoluteLayout because it's super easy to center a Label with that.  For this solution, I changed your Nav Bar's StackLayout to an AbsoluteLayout and added the layout parameters in code behind.

The XAML:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="NavBarLayout" HeightRequest="45" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
     <Button x:Name="btnBack" TextColor="White" FontSize="40" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="&lt;" />
     <Label x:Name="labelTitle" TextColor="White" FontSize="24" Text="Hello World!" YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The code behind:

```
public MyPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        NavBarLayout.Children.Add (
            btnBack,
            // Adds the Button on the top left corner, with 10% of the navbar's width and 100% height
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 0.1, 1),
            // The proportional flags tell the layout to scale the value using [0, 1] -> [0%, 100%]
            AbsoluteLayoutFlags.HeightProportional | AbsoluteLayoutFlags.WidthProportional
        );

        NavBarLayout.Children.Add(
            labelTitle,
            // Using 0.5 will center it and the layout takes the size of the element into account
            // 0.5 will center, 1 will right align
            // Adds in the center, with 90% of the navbar's width and 100% of height
            new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 1),
            AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All
        );
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely the type of solution I was looking for. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a very old post but for people still having a similar issue, I solved it using:

```
 HorizontalOptions="Center"
```

on the `StackLayout` definition in the XAML. The full definition I used is as follows:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="ButtonLayout" HorizontalOptions="Center">
```